# Referencing Non-Scalar Closures c#

Tags: c#, linq, closures

I'm new to C# and especially to linq.

Here's my problem:

```
        Player Hero = new Player();
        Hero.ImageURL = LBimage.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        Hero.Name = HeroName.Text;
        Hero.HP = 200;
        Hero.HPMAX = 200;
        Hero.PosX = 3;
        Hero.PosY = 3;
        Hero.XP = 0;
        DB.Player.Add(Hero);
        Item w = new Item();
        w.ItemDamage = 100;
        w.ItemName = "Griffe de Lynx2";
        w.Player.Add(Hero);
        db.Item.Add(w);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var query = (from item in db.Item where (item.Player == Hero)select item).ToList();

        List<Item> Inventory = query;
        foreach (var item in Inventory)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ItemName);
        }
```

I want to create an inventory for each player who register in the game. For this I have 3 tables, Player, Item and PlayerObject.

The idea is to fill the relation table with two columns PlayerID and ObjectID. I would put every time I found an item with a player the item id and the player id in it.

The problem is as you can see up there that I can't do a query that allow me to retrieve the list of items that the hero have.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: If I understood properly, you are asking [how to make _many to many_ relationship with Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship.aspx).

Comment: I guess that's the case. I just took a look at your link, my DB does not look like that in visual studio. I have only two table linked by * * and PlayerObject does not appear to be here in the model i generated. but i have it in navigation properties.

Comment: @AngourIsmail google _relations with EF_ and you'll find lots of resource.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity framework designer, ensure that the tables are linked as a many to many relation ship.  When the entity framework generates the database scripts, the required relation table will be automatically created.

In the code to retrieve all the items for a player, try the following.

```
IEnumerable<Items> itemEnum = DB.Player.Where(p=>p.PlayerID == pid).Items;
List<Items> itemList = itemEnum.ToList();
```

Where `pid` is the id of the player whose inventory you wish to find.

Comment: The problem is that i can't access PlayerID cause it's an Object. i tried 
             var query = (from item in db.Item where (item.Player.Select(jl => jl.ID) == Hero.ID)select item).ToList();
but i have an issue with the 

item.Player.Select(jl => jl.ID) == Hero.ID

cause item.Player.Select return a list so i can't make a comparison between it.

Comment: @AgourIsmail Perhaps you are looking at this the wrong way around.  Instead of searching for all items and then filter for the player, search for player and list his items. eg, `List<Items> items = DB.Player.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.PlayerID == pid).Items.ToList()`

Comment: Thanks a lot I figured out how to do it.